# How to determine if Ubuntu system needs a reboot?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, ansible

I recently applied a kernel patch (mix of debian 10 and Ubuntu 18.04) using ansible. I am trying to figure out a way to check if each machine being updated has been, or needs, a reboot. I've read that `test -f /var/run/reboot-required` is the official indicator however I've noticed this is not always true. Sometimes the file is there after a kernel upgrade, sometimes not. I'm not using LivePatch so any time there is a kernel update, I need to schedule reboots of all these systems.

In ansible, it was straightforward enough to test for the existence of the file above but since that's not consistent, I came up with the bash code below to test the running kernel version against the newest kernel image laying under `/boot`. This isn't exactly something you can plug right into ansible without a lot of hammering.

Is there a better way to determine if a reboot is needed?

```
if [[ $(uname -r) != .*"$(ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | sort -V | tail -1)"*. ]]; then
   echo "Needs reboot. Running kernel $(uname -r) is older than $(ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | sort -u | tail -1)"
fi
```

Comment: The "reboot required" flag files are actually `/var/run/reboot*`. There can be more than one

Comment: Strange. `find /var/run | grep reboot` comes up empty. The running kernel on one system is `4.15.0-166-generic` and the latest is `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-167-generic`. I've never known a kernel patch that didn't require a reboot so something is amiss with documentation or the system (`/var/` is only 18% capacity)

Comment: @waltinator Provides the correct path towards the ideal solution. Complicated ansible tasks to compare running versus installed kernel versions may bring you to the answer you are looking for, but the system already has built-in and standardized mechanisms to check for this condition. Relying on those makes for better portability of your code.

Comment: @0xSheepdog I see their comment. Do you not understand `find /var/run | grep reboot`?

Answer (score 1):

Restart may be required not only after installing a new kernel but also after updates of microcode, glibc, SSL libs, etc.. So some more events will require a restart.

In RHEL there are utilities based around the package manager available, `yum-utils` which contains a `needs-restarting` script to query if it would be necessary to do so after applying updates.

In Debian based distribution is a similar [`needrestart`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=needrestart) available, which [check if restart is required after updates](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/needrestart).

**Example** (based on RHEL 7)

After resolving the dependencies

```yaml
- name: Install basic admin tools
  yum:
    name: yum-utils
    state: latest
```

checks are simple as

```yaml
- name: Check if reboot_required
  shell:
    cmd: "needs-restarting -r"
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: reboot_required.rc != 0 and reboot_required.rc != 1
  check_mode: false
  register: reboot_required

- name: Report reboot_required
  debug:
    msg: "{{  reboot_required.rc | bool }} "
  changed_when: reboot_required.rc == 1
  check_mode: false
```

and resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Report reboot_required] **************************************************
ok: [test1.example.com] => {
    "msg": "True "
}
ok: [test2.example.com] => {
    "msg": "False "
}
```

You may need to change the dependency resolving parts, as well to address the parameter according [`man needrestart`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/needrestart/needrestart.1.en.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my solution, in case it's of use to anyone else.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  vars:
    kernel_version: "{{ ansible_kernel }}"

  tasks:

    # sort -V specifically sorts software versions :)
    - name: find newest kernel under /boot
      shell   : ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | sort -V | tail -1
      register: latest_kernel

    # running kernel does not match latest kernel - can't do <> comparison since text is involved
    - name: test kernel versions different
      when: kernel_version not in latest_kernel.stdout
      debug:
        msg: "WARNING: needs reboot - running kernel {{ kernel_version }} was not found in variable {{ latest_kernel.stdout }}"
```