# Ansible - How to reboot the server based on condition?

Tags: text-processing, ansible

I wrote the playbook to apply the security patches on Linux servers, the only part remaining is to write the task to restart the patched server.

Below is the content of the task to apply the patches

```yaml
- name: Deploying Security Packages                              
  shell: "yum update --security -y"                              
  register: progress                                             
  when: deploypackages == "y"                                    
                                                                 
- name: Installed Packages                                       
  debug:                                                         
    msg: "{{ progress.stdout_lines | regex_search('complete') }}"
  #when: progress.changed | regex_search('complete')
```

I was looking for a filter to look in the output for the word in registered variable, if it is `completed` and `kernel` and then reboot the server.

Thanks

**Attempt 1 - Failed**

For testing purpose I've changed `kernel` with `xz-libs`, but it is failing when reaches the `when` condition.

```yaml
---
- name: Deploying Security Packages
  #shell: "yum update --security -y"
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    security: yes
  register: yum_update
  when: deploypackages == "y"

- name: Installed Packages
  debug:
    msg: " Packages installed Successfully "
  when:
    - yum_update.changed
    - yum_update.stdout | regex_search('xz-libs', ignorecase=True ) is not none
```

It gives this error

```
TASK [deploying_security_updates : Deploying Security Packages] **********************
changed: [192.168.8.26]

    TASK [deploying_security_updates : Installed Packages] *******************************
    fatal: [192.168.8.26]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'yum_update.stdout | regex_search('*xz-libs*', ignorecase=True ) is not none' failed. The error was: nothing to repeat\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/sysadmin/ansible_files/play-security-update/roles/deploying_security_updates/tasks/main.yaml': line 11, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Installed Packages\n  ^ here\n"}
```

## Debug

```
- name: Deploying Security Packages                                                
  yum:                                                                             
    name: '*'                                                                      
    state: latest                                                                  
    security: yes                                                                  
  register: yum_update                                                             
  when: deploypackages == "y"                                                      
                                                                                   
- name: Installed Packages                                                         
  debug:                                                                           
    #msg: " Packages installed Successfully "                                      
    msg: " {{ yum_update.stdout | regex_search('xz-libs', ignorecase=True ) }}"    
  #when:                                                                           
  #  - yum_update.changed                                                          
  #  - yum_update.stdout | regex_search('*xz-libs*', ignorecase=True ) is not none 



Do you want to deploy Packages: y

PLAY [To Apply Security Patches on Linux Servers] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.8.26]

TASK [Condition Failed! Wrong User Input] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.8.26]

TASK [check_for_updates : Looking for Package Updates] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.8.26]

TASK [check_for_updates : Printing Available Updates] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.8.26]

TASK [deploying_security_updates : Deploying Security Packages] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.8.26]

TASK [deploying_security_updates : Installed Packages] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.8.26]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ( {{ yum_update.stdout | regex_search('xz-libs', ignorecase=True ) }}): expected string or buffer"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.8.26               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

## Debug Output

```
ok: [192.168.8.26] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "changes": {
            "installed": [],
            "updated": [
                [
                    "xz",
                    "5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote"
                ],
                [
                    "xz-libs",
                    "5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote"
                ]
            ]
        },
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "results": [
            "Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-\n              : manager\nThis system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.\n --> device-mapper-persistent-data-0.7.3-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.170-6.el7_9.5.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libgnomekbd-3.26.0-3.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> cryptsetup-python-2.0.3-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin-1.1.10-2.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> libstoragemgmt-1.6.2-4.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> PackageKit-gtk3-module-1.1.10-2.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.149-8.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> setroubleshoot-plugins-3.0.67-3.el7.noarch from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> libdrm-2.4.91-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> mesa-dri-drivers-18.3.4-12.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> subscription-manager-plugin-container-1.24.51-1.el7_9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> firewalld-0.6.3-13.el7_9.noarch from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> gdb-7.6.1-114.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> grubby-8.28-26.el7.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> hostname-3.13-3.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> 32:bind-libs-lite-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.9.x86_64 from rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n --> abrt-dbus-2.1.11-52.el7.x86_64 from @anaconda/7.6 removed (updateinfo)\n --> unzip-6.0-21.el7.x86_64 from @rhel-remote removed (updateinfo)\n
 Package xz-libs.x86_64 0:5.2.2-2.el7_9 will be an update\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n\nDependencies Resolved\n\n================================================================================\n Package         Arch           Version               Repository           Size\n================================================================================\nUpdating:\n xz              x86_64         5.2.2-2.el7_9         rhel-remote         229 k\n xz-libs         x86_64         5.2.2-2.el7_9         rhel-remote         103 k\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nUpgrade  2 Packages\n\nTotal download size: 332 k\nDownloading packages:\nNo Presto metadata available for rhel-remote\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nTotal                                              1.3 MB/s | 332 kB  00:00     \nRunning transaction check\nRunning transaction test\nTransaction test succeeded\nRunning transaction\n  Updating   : xz-libs-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                 1/4 \n  Updating   : xz-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                      2/4 \n  Cleanup    : xz-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                        3/4 \n  Cleanup    : xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                   4/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-libs-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                 1/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-5.2.2-2.el7_9.x86_64                                      2/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                   3/4 \n  Verifying  : xz-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64                                        4/4 \n\nUpdated:\n  xz.x86_64 0:5.2.2-2.el7_9            xz-libs.x86_64 0:5.2.2-2.el7_9           \n\nComplete!\n"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.8.26               : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Why are you not using the `yum` module? Using `shell` makes it way harder to parse output and to create idempotence.

Comment: I used yum module, but it doesn't do anything. Even though there are secuirty packages. i used "yum: \ state:  latest\ security: yes"

Comment: And why would it? Read the docs. You are not naming any packages `state: latest` could apply to.

Comment: yes i missed the name: '*' part , now it does install. Now can you help me with original question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the task is completed and the word *kernel* in the output has been mentioned you would get the following task:

```
- name: "Deploying Security Packages"
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: '*'
    security: yes
    state: latest
  register: yum_update

- name: "Just debug for now"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "This should be a reboot"
  when:
    - yum_update.changed
    - (yum_update.results[0] | regex_search('kernel')) is not none
```

The two `-` with the when means a logical `AND` so the update should be changed and thus completed, otherwise it would fail, and in the output of the stdout there should be the word matching kernel. If the word is not there the check will output a `none` according the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions).

Comment: It failed, Description added under "Attempt 1 - Failed" in Question

Comment: Could you try to just use the debug on the regex line like so: `msg: "{{ yum_update.stdout | regex_search('xz-libs', ignorecase=True ) }}"` without a when, just print what it returns?

Comment: Hello @Mr, Diba, i updated the task and enabled the debug , tasks and run is in question below Debug heading

Comment: Now I'm curious what `msg: "{{ yum_update }}"` actually holds?

Comment: I added the output under "Debug Output" in question, And i think yum module don't write in stdout, so i used yum_update.results

Comment: I see that the `yum` plugin output differs from the `apt` I used to test this. The errors you where getting was because there was no `stdout` variable, so it had nothing to parse. You could try to use the `results` instead of `stdout` to check if the kernel has been touched. I have updated my answer. Not entirely sure of this works: `msg: "{{ yum_update.results | regex_search('xz-libs', ignorecase=True ) }}"`

Comment: No it slaps me with this error,

fatal: [192.168.8.26]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(yum_update.results | regex_search('Complete')) is not none' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if (yum_update.results | regex_search('Kernel')) is not none %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/sysadmin/ansible_files/play-security-update/roles/deploying_security_updates/tasks/main.yamlThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Installed Packages\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: Well it could be because `results` is a dictionary, could you try: `yum_update.results[0]`?

Comment: Well well well Mr.Diba it did work, and it is dictionary and i did searched how to access it like an array element. Can you please direct me to some article on how to access dictonary .

Comment: Great to hear that it worked, did it solve your problem? If so could you please accept the answer? I have searched for some information about dictionaries but there is not a lot of information available on the specific topic as it is "just part of YAML". If you have a specific YAML question please open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Please take note that a restart may be required not only after installing a new kernel but also after updates of microcode, glibc, SSL libs, etc.. So some more events will require a restart and needs to be checked too.

In RHEL there are utilities based around the native OS package manager available, in example `yum-utils` which contains a `needs-restarting` script to query if it would be necessary to do so after applying updates.

**Example** (based on RHEL 7)

After resolving the dependencies

```yaml
- name: Install basic admin tools
  yum:
    name: yum-utils
    state: latest
```

checks are simple as

```yaml
- name: Check if reboot_required
  shell:
    cmd: "needs-restarting -r"
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: reboot_required.rc != 0 and reboot_required.rc != 1
  check_mode: false
  register: reboot_required

- name: Report reboot_required
  debug:
    msg: "{{  reboot_required.rc | bool }} "
  changed_when: reboot_required.rc == 1
  check_mode: false
```

and resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Report reboot_required] **************************************************
ok: [test1.example.com] => {
    "msg": "True "
}
ok: [test2.example.com] => {
    "msg": "False "
}
```

Packages for checking if a restart is required are also available for other distributions.

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to determine if system needs a reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690333/266568)

---

Additionally and depending on the infrastructure and environement, one could left the reboot fully automated to the system in example via cronjobs like

```bash
# Reboot cron job
# /etc/cron.d/

# mm hh dom mon dow user command
  59  0   *   *   * root needs-restarting -r || /usr/sbin/shutdown --no-wall -r +1
```